# WPF Display age from datepicker using data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datepicker

I have a little `window` with a `datepicker` and a `label`. The goal is to display the age of a person whose birth date is picked. I'm using MVVM light for this and I need to use the `ViewModel.cs`. Can I do it using only `XAML`? If no, how to pull this off?

My ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace zh1_beteges
{
    public class PatientVM : ViewModelBase
    {
        Patient b = null;

        int age;
        DatePicker DP;
        public int Age
        {
            get { return age; }
            set { Set(ref age, value); }
        }
        public Patient B
        {
            get
            {
                return b;
            }
            set { Set(ref b, value); }
        }
        public PatientVM(DatePicker DP)
        {
            this.DP = DP;
        }
        public PatientVM(Patient b, DatePicker DP)
        {
            this.B = b;
            this.DP = DP;
            age = DateTime.Today.Year - b.DateOfBirth.Year;
        }


    }
}
```

and my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="zh1_beteges.BetegAdatai"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:zh1_beteges"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="BetegAdatai" Height="314.894" Width="512.766"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    >
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Patient name:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
           FontSize="14" Margin="10,0,10,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
    </Label>
    <Label Content="PlaceOfBirth: " HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
           FontSize="14" Margin="10,0,10,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
    </Label>
    <Label Content="date of birth:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
           FontSize="14" Margin="10,0,10,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
    </Label>
    <Label Content="TAJ:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
           FontSize="14" Margin="10,0,10,0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">
    </Label>
    <Label Content="Age:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
           FontSize="14" Margin="10,0,10,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">
    </Label>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Age}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
           FontSize="14" Margin="10,0,10,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3">
    </Label>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="170,5,170,5"
            Content="OK" FontSize="14">
    </Button>
    <DatePicker x:Name="DP" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" DisplayDateStart="2016/01/01"
                SelectedDate="{Binding Path=B.SzuletesiDatum}">
    </DatePicker>
    <TextBox Margin="10,5,10,5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
             Text="{Binding Path=B.Name}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" >
    </TextBox>
    <TextBox Margin="10,5,10,5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
             Text="{Binding Path=B.PlaceOfBirth}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" >
    </TextBox>
    <TextBox Margin="10,5,10,5" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
             Text="{Binding Path=B.TAJ}"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

And my Xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace zh1_beteges
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for PatientData.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class PatientData : Window
    {
        public PatientVM bvm;
        public PatientData()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bvm = new PatientVM(DP);
            this.DataContext = bvm;
        }
        public PatientData(Patient b)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bvm = new PatientVM(b,DP);
            this.DataContext = bvm;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this using a custom converter. Custom converters allow you to bind a data to another value converted to or from that data. In your case you need a converter that converts selected date to time passed that date.

You should create a class like this:

```
public class DatetimeToPassedDateConverter : IValueConverter,MarkupExtension
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value is DateTime)
            return DateTime.Now-(DateTime)value;
        else
            return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Convert back which is not required in your case
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

And then use it in your XAML like this:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=DP,Path=SelectedDate,Converter={namespace:DatetimeToPassedDateConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
       FontSize="14" Margin="10,0,10,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3">
</Label>
```

For more information about custom converters see [this article](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html).

Comment: Thanks for the tip.
I created a class and added this label, however I get some `namespace was not found`. How to add that into the `XAML` code?

Comment: see the top of your xaml page. In the initial section you see some "xmlns:xxx=yyy". Follow the same syntax and add the namespace for your class in there

Comment: Trying now according to the tutorial you linked. the converted class is inside the namespace where all my other stuff lives and is public, no luck just yet. 

I'm doing this btw:

`    <Window.Resources>
        <local:DatetimeToPassedDateConverter x:Key="dateConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>`

Comment: We inherited MarkupExtension to avoid that. Just change "namespace" to "local" in Converter={namespace:DatetimeToPassedDateConverter}

Comment: And it WORKS! All the help appreciated :D

Answer (score 1):

You can create property inside `PatientVM` called `SelectedDate`:

```
private DateTime? selectedDate;
public DateTime? SelectedDate
{
    get
    {
        return selectedDate;
    }
    set
    {
        selectedDate = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedDate");
        DateSelectionChangedExecute();
    }
}
```

And then in `DateSelectionChangedExecute` calculate the `Age` (this method should be improved for example to prevent negative age):

```
private void DateSelectionChangedExecute()
{
     if (SelectedDate != null && SelectedDate.Value != null)
         Age = DateTime.Now.Year - SelectedDate.Value.Year;
}
```

And bind `SelectedDate` to your `DatePicker` in xaml:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="DP" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" DisplayDateStart="2016/01/01"
                SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate}">
</DatePicker>
```

Thanks to this every time the `SelectedDate` is changed the `Age` will be calculated.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but with the help of @Emad I could make his solution work.